# Why does \euscr{P} not work correctly?

Tags: math-mode, packages

I'm trying to write the "power of a set" in LaTeX, but I don't think that the usual ways to do it look like the handwritten letter (I usually write it as `\mathcal{P}`, but would like to find another way). Someone answered here, in another context, with an option I would like to use: `\euscr{P}`, but for some reason I can't quite understand, it doesn't work for me, and looks exactly like `\mathcal{P}`. Can someone help me to make this work? I think the problem is somewhere in my preamble, maybe conflicting packages? Here is a minimal (non)working example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage{dsfont}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage[left=2.1 cm,top=2.3 cm,right=2.3 cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{authblk}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{resizegather}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{amstext}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
    \usepackage{doc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}
    \usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=[rgb]{0.6,0.2,0.8}}
    \usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
    \let\euscr\mathscr \let\mathscr\relax
    \usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
    \begin{document} 
    \title{\textbf{Chapter I: Differentiable Manifolds}}
    \author{}\date{}
    \maketitle
    If $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq\euscr{P}(M_1)$, where $\mathcal{P}(M_1)$ refers to the power set of $M_1$, then:
    \[F\bigg(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\bigg)=\bigcup_{i\in I}F(A_i)\hspace*{0.7cm}\wedge\hspace*{0.7cm}F\bigg(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\bigg)=\bigcap_{i\in I}F(A_i)\]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please update your code to be a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure about what you mean by that... My code does compile in my latex version...

Comment: you should never load `epsfig` at all but why  the option in `\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}` are you using latex+dvips rather than pdflatex?

Comment: A MWE is not only compilable, it is the smallest amount of code required to show your problem, so that we can help you without having to dig in tons of lines of code.

Comment: Yes, when I compile I run latex, dvips and ps2pdf. I'm not an expert, just found that this worked at stuck with it. However, I'm really puzzled now because the minimal example I posted _does_ work as I want it to... Maybe it doesn't if I try to use too many alphabets? I'm really confused...

Comment: Oh, thank you for the explanation user124577. I added the packages too because I didn't know if any of them was responsible for the problem, but if it's better I'll remove the unnecesary ones.

Comment: if you use too many alphabets then you get an error (and you should put the error text into your question) latex will not silently drop letters.

Comment: The current code does not demonstrate the problem.  Please check that your tex installation is up-to-date.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I actually was getting a "too many alphabets" error in the terminal, but missed it, and that's why the final pdf wasn't registering the changes. It works now, but do you know how can I use more alphabets without getting this error message? I actually need them in my work.

Comment: usually it is possible, but you should ask a question about that with an example document that shows that error, for example see the bm package documenttaion and setting `\newcommmand\bmmax{2}` might be enough

Comment: If I use \newcommand\bmmax{2}, I get the error "\bmmax already defined". But thank you very much anyway, I'll ask a question about it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands work correctly, You do not say what you expect.

If I cut your example to a more reasonable size then.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\let\euscr\mathscr \let\mathscr\relax
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
\begin{document} 
$P\euscr{P}\mathcal{P}\mathscr{P}$
\end{document}
```

So all the P work, only you can decide which you want.

Comment: Yes, your example works, but I don't understand why. I mean, when I compile my entire document, the second and third "Ps" you write look exactly the same, like the third. Do you have any idea why this could be happening? Am I maybe using too many alphabets? However, I'm not getting the "too many alphabets" error...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I actually was getting the "too many alphabets" error in my bigger code, but missed it, and that's why it wasn't showing the pdf right. Thank you for your answer!